# jooq aggregate functions

Tags: java, sql, aggregate-functions, jooq

I am trying to use aggregate function like max, min in jOOQ and refering their **[mannual](http://www.jooq.org/manual/DSL/FUNCTIONS/#N10B7F)** but I am not understanding their examples that how they created max function and used it in their example. Can you please help me out on this. Please provide simple example if possible.

**Problem I am facing**
In jOOQ mannual example for aggregate function max is as follows

```
create.select(max(ID).add(1).as("next_id")).from(T_AUTHOR);
```

but when I used max in my query I am getting **function max is undefined.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of static imports is documented in various places of the jOOQ tutorial and manual. Whenever you see a "standalone function" in the manual, you can safely assume that it was static imported from [`org.jooq.impl.DSL`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html).

See the example taken from the tutorial:

```
// For convenience, always static import your generated tables and
// jOOQ functions to decrease verbosity:
import static test.generated.Tables.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step6/
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/the-manual/

Hence, the example you're trying to run will require that you either

- static import `org.jooq.impl.DSL.max`
- fully qualify `DSL.max` in your query