# jOOQ: How to call Sql User defined Function Within Select Query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have to execute Select query with a function call in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) how to do it? I have to write this type of jOOQ Query.

```
Select Cola,col2,Col3, f_feeAmount(arg) col4 from SomeTable
```

How to write jOOQ Code for this?

```
SelectQuery<Record> selectQueryFee = transRefundFee.selectQuery();
selectQueryFee.addSelect(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE_RSN,AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER,AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.PAYMENT_OPTION);
selectQueryFee.addSelect(f_feeAmount(arg));
```

But `f_feeAmount` is not recognized by jOOQ because its a User defined function.

Comment: did you try to look for tutorials?

Comment: Yes i knw how to write simple query but with function its look some issue

Comment: I think this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896538/jooq-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-defined functions are generated in a `Routines` class. You can just static-import all methods from that class:

```
import static com.example.generated.Routines.*;
```

And then, writing `f_feeAmount(arg)` should be fine.

See also this page of the jOOQ manual about [generated global artefacts](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/codegen-globals/).